# How to configure autofs5 timeout on per-filesystem basis?

Tags: linux, debian, autofs

Because of a show-stopping bug in Debian autofs 4, I just upgraded to autofs5.
It is not honoring the timeout option in my `auto.master` file:

```
/var/autofs/removable /etc/auto.removable --timeout=2
```

I use this map for thumb drives and so on; I don't want a general default timeout of 2 seconds.

I did some digging and although the `--timeout` option worked in autofs 4, and it appears in some examples on the Web, it is not actually sanctioned (or even mentioned) in the documentation for the `auto.master` file.  So I don't feel I can report the problem as a bug.

**How can I get autofs5 to timeout after 2 seconds only on designated filesystems?**

---

Update: I am using a Debian-packaged autofs5, version 5.0.4-3.2.

Comment: Can you please tell us the exact version of the used autofs package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** the rest of my answer is mostly off-topic. You're doing it the right way, but the feature was only introduced in `autofs` 5.0.6. From the git repository:

> Author: Ian Kent 
>   Date:   Fri May 25 12:28:56 2012 +0800
>
> ```
> autofs-5.0.6 - move timeout to map_source
>
> Move the map entry timeout field from "struct autofs_point" to
> "struct map_source".
>
> The result of this change is that an individual timeout may be
> set for each direct map master map entry.
> ```

---

Unfortunately only maps can have a custom timeout (overwriting the `automount(8)` one using `--timeout`), not entries themselves.

This limitation goes down as low as the Linux kernel itself, which only offers an `AUTOFS_DEV_IOCTL_TIMEOUT_CMD` `ioctl` per `autofs` filesystem, applied on all its mounts. You can find more information in `Documentation/filesystems/autofs4-mount-control.txt` in the kernel sources.

The best solution I can suggest is to split your entries by timeout into separate maps. This unfortunately means that you'll have different parent directories for your mounts.

If that's a big problem, you could look into UnionFS or similar, but there is no such feature in the official Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

--timeout=n wasn't always implemented in autofs version 5. Try using -t n instead.